# How to make XeLaTeX display nothing except warnings and errors?

Tags: errors, xetex, miktex, warnings

When I run XeLaTeX

```
XeLaTeX --max-print-line=2048 --c-style-errors --interaction=nonstopmode "C:\Report.tex"
```

I get this output

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("C:/Report.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, arabic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, ngerman-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usenglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
No file Report.aux.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ref:dummy' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.

[1] ("Report.aux")

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )
Output written on Report.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on Report.log.
```

But I really couldn't care less what hyphenation patterns are available or what folder MiKTeX is installed in... I just want to see the warnings and errors. So instead I'd like to see something like:

```
C:/Report.tex:18: warning: Citation `ref:dummy' on page 1 undefined
```

Is there any built-in way to have it **only** output **both** warnings *and* errors, or do I have to write my own shell script?

Comment: Are you looking for `-quiet` option?

Comment: @HarishKumar Is that MiKTeX specific? Sounds useful...

Comment: @HarishKumar It is not there. I looked before asking. Also, attempting to use it returns a complaint that the option is unrecognised for both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr Then it seems it is miktex only: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cIpAy.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/rPoy7.png

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. What is odd is that I was sure I'd used this in the past for pdfLaTeX...

Comment: @HarishKumar: `-quiet` also suppresses warnings, which is not what I want. Same with `-interaction=batchmode`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: This is what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GwK3o.png

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes it does suppress some (most of) times. Then there no built in option for you as seen from the list (`xelatex -help` from cmd).

Comment: @HarishKumar: I see... if it's not possible then feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: You may appreciate the `silence` package, which (from the abstract) 'is designed to filter out unwanted warnings and error messages. Entire packages (including LaTeX) can be censored, but very specific messages can be targeted too. TEX’s messages are left untouched.'  Disclaimer: I've never used it.

Comment: Have you tried the log parser that comes with TexWorks? It gives just the warnings and errors.